# Using Visual Studio comparer tool with VisualHG

Tags: visual-studio-2013, mercurial, visualhg

I'm using Mercurial with VisualHG extension.

Is there any way to change the KDiff3 code comparer to the Visual Studio Compare and Merge tool?

Answer (score 1):

I use [VisualHg2](https://bitbucket.org/lmn/visualhg2) with VS 2012.

In Visual Studio.

Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> VisualHg

Dialog should show a text field with a label.

"Custom diff tool (leave blank to use Visual Studio diff)"

I assume the field shows KDiff3 path for you, if so then delete it.

Comment: Hi. Thx for respond. Yeah, I know about **Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> VisualHg**. And **External Diff Tool Command** textbox is empty. But it's still using KDiff3 by default. Also I tried to select diff tool from list. But I didn't find the VS default tool.

Answer (score 1):

Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> VisualHg

In the text field:

```
"$(ProgramFiles (x86))\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /diff "$(Base)" "$(Mine)"
```